# Why is pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent: not part of the datasource protocol?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uipickerview

working with a UIPickerView gets me a bit confused.

Why is pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent: not part of the datasource protocol? This is the main method to get the data onto the view. But its not part of the datasource protocol but of the delegate protocol.

And why is this method optional? I don't have to implement it but without it I don't see much. But I have to implement numberOfComponentsInPickerView: and numberOfRowsInComponent:.

This feels incomplete and not right.